# Night light is not working

Tags: display, settings, night-light

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and my night light recently stopped working. I did no changes whatsoever, it just stopped working. What could be a possible fix?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Did it lose track of your location?

Comment: @ajgringo619 No, it didn't lose track of my location. One day it was working, the next it wasn't. I didn't change or do anything consequential.

Comment: What does `systemctl status geoclue` show? In the past with redshift, if I restarted this service it began to work again.

Comment: It happened to me too. I have it set to manual timing, from 05:00 to 04:59. When it broke, even the nightlight icon did not show up in the panel. But I noticed that my monitors (laptop + external HDMI) have disappeared from the _Settings_ app's _Color_ settings sidebar item. I set the preinstalled `D50` color profile for my laptop's screen on that _Color_ settings UI. But now only my printer had shown up to set a color profile to: the monitors did not. I think it's related. A reboot however restored everything: the _Color_ settings UI, the laptop screen color profile, and night light.